# How to fix "Only allowed to have one file passed in with extension '.AdditionalFile.txt'"

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a unity project in Visual Studio Code.
But I can't get rid off the error `Only allowed to have one file passed in with extension '.AdditionalFile.txt' Roslyn(USG0001)`:
[image]

I've already tried disabling it with `.editorconfig`:

```
[*.csproj]
dotnet_diagnostic.USG0001.severity = none
```

And I can't find any information about `USG0001`.

How can I fix or disable this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been searching for an answer forever and finally found one!
Create a .globalconfig file in the root of your project and insert this into it:

```
is_global = true

dotnet_diagnostic.USG0001.severity = none
```

Comment: Note that I need to add this in .editorconfig for vscode.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone on Unity encountering these warnings after VS update, all you need to do to get rid of them, is to update your Visual Studio Editor package to the latest (2.0.22 as of now) version.

Window > Package Manager > Visual Studio Editor > Update