USG0001 warnings. Why are these warning appearing in my Visual Studio Editor?
I am creating a project in Unity version 2022.3.71F using Visual Studio version 17.9.6. I am receiving multiple warning in the editor as indicated in the attached image. I can find no information on this warning as to its cause. I cannot suppress the warnings. I am concerned about the effects this warning might have on my build. At present they do not appear to effect the functionality of my project.
How do I determine the meaning of these warnings and how best do I address them?
I have tried many days of web research to discover anything about the USG0001 warning to no avail.

Apparently the image I refer to in the post did not transfer. Here is a sample of one of the 46 warnings: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Warning USG0001 Only allowed to have one file passed in with extension '.AdditionalFile.txt' Unity.InternalAPIEngineBridge.001 E:\My Data\Unity Projects\Mandolin Fret Quest\Unity.InternalAPIEngineBridge.001.csproj 1 Active

Does this help you? I know, it's VSCode, but maybe it can help you regardless: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77095397/how-to-fix-only-allowed-to-have-one-file-passed-in-with-extension-additionalf

Unfortuneately no, but thanks for trying. I don't want to suppress the warnings (I will if I have to), but I want to get to the root of the issue.
